# Issue with require in PHP

Tags: php

In my app I have a file called /var/www/app/admin/send_email.php

I want to include attachments to the emails so I have set up the following:

```
if ($has_form_attachment) {      
  include('/var/www/app/includes/dynamic/php/StandardEmailAttachments/' . $id_standard_email . '.php');
  // send the email
}
```

The problem is that when I try to send the email I get the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Pdf/Page.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/app/includes/dynamic/php/StandardEmailAttachments/Zend/Pdf.php on line 23
```

However, this file is definitely present:

```
[11:41 PM]-[vagrant@app]-[/var/www/app/includes/dynamic/php/StandardEmailAttachments/Zend]
$ ls
Auth.php  Cache.php  Config.php  Exception.php  Fonts/  Loader.php  Memory/  Memory.php  Pdf/  Pdf.php
```

I think the problem is that in send_email.php I am including 53.php, and in 53.php I am including Zend/Pdf.php, but I am not sure how to get around this…

```
<?php 

// 53.php

require_once 'Zend/Pdf.php';

try
{
    $pdf = Zend_Pdf::load(‘forms/pdf-template.pdf');
}
catch (Zend_Pdf_Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}

$pdfData = $pdf->render();
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private", false);
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"form.pdf\";");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($pdfData));
echo $pdfData;
exit;
```

If I call the /includes/dynamic/php/StandardEmailAttachments/53.php directly from the browser it works correctly, it’s just when I try and run admin/send_email.php that generates the error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is 53.php and "Zend" in the same folder?

Comment: Sorry, yes they are:

[vagrant@app]-[/var/www/app/includes/dynamic/php/StandardEmailAttachments]
$ ls
53.php  forms/  Zend/

Answer (score 0):

Use of relative paths should really be avoided due to problems like this one.    Not sure what version of ZF you are using, but the obvious question is -- why are you not using a composer.json and autoloading?

With that said the answer to your question is in the title of this blog post:

[PHP: include paths are relative to the current working directory](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/10/php-include-paths-are-relative-to.html)

This is why it works differently when you run a command line script from one directory vs. when you run it via the webserver.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Within the Zend folder there are many require calls that are relative i.e. require_once(Zend/Pdf/Page.php); Does this mean I need to update every path within Zend folder to absolute paths?

Comment: The assumption of frameworks is that you are going to use autoloading, since they are class libraries.  You simply need ZF to be in your php include path or to use an autoloader.